# Reference to element in JSON

Tags: python, json

Let's say I have a simple json variable and I can access it's values like this:

```
import json

# some JSON:
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York", "ID_info":{ "first_name":"John", "year":1995}}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["age"]) #prints 30
print(y["ID_info"]["first_name"]) #prints John
```

Is there a way to replace the value in `"first_name"` so that it finds it in `"name"`?

I would expect something like:

```
import json

# some JSON:
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York", "ID_info":{ "first_name":$Ref("name"), "year":1995}}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["age"]) #prints 30
print(y["ID_info"]["first_name"]) # I'd like it to print "John"
```

PS this is a simple example IRL I have nested jsons I want to simplify :)

Comment: Json doesn't have references like that. Json is literally "Javascript object notation", just a simple dump of js object - objects of classes (dictionaries with string keys), lists, strings, null, booleans, numbers. That's all. Here you have a nice visuals how json works: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: What h4z3 says is obviously correct, JSON inherently does not have references but as @emilyisstewpid correctly points out and links there is a way to achieve references, it simply is a matter of you agreeing on an encoding what references should look like and then implementing a lookup based on them.

Comment: What is the use case of this? if you want to get some [search for] input from user and allow for them to use e.g. `first name` instead of `name` why not simply "normalize" the input to available keys? In other words this looks like XY problem to me.

Comment: @emilyisstewpid yes it does :)

Comment: @buran it can happen that you need the same element far in the same tree. although you are right on thinking that a good JSON structure is important before adding these references.